# Read only lines that start with variable passed to the script in bash

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have `BASH` script like below

```
#!/bin/bash

current_batch_date=$1
export control_dir=/x/home/$USER

while IFS=, read -r run_project_name application subject_area source_db target_db error_db source_tbl target_tbl error_tbl
do
    export proj_num=$(echo $run_project_name | cut -d_ -f1)
    export proj_id="${proj_num:1}"
    export P_LOAD_FROM_DATE=$(date -d "$current_batch_date - 1 days" +%Y-%m-%d)
    export from_batch_seq_num=5
    export P_LOAD_TO_DATE=$(date -d "$current_batch_date - 1 days" +%Y-%m-%d)
    export to_batch_seq_num=5
    export run_main_session_id=000000
    export extract_from_ts=$(echo $P_LOAD_FROM_DATE "00:00:00")
    export extract_to_ts=$(echo $P_LOAD_TO_DATE "00:00:00")
    export source_db=${source_db}
    export target_db=${target_db}
    export error_db=${error_db}
    export source_tbl=${source_tbl}
    export target_tbl=${target_tbl}
    export error_tbl${error_tbl}
    export current_timestamp=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    export critical_chain_ind='Y'
    export final_source_count=0
    export final_target_count=0
    export hop_validation='PASSED'
    export file_ext=$(date "+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
    echo "${proj_id},${proj_num},,${run_project_name},${application},${subject_area},${P_LOAD_FROM_DATE},${from_batch_seq_num},${P_LOAD_TO_DATE},${to_batch_seq_num},${run_main_session_id},${extract_from_ts},${extract_to_ts},${source_db^^},${target_db^^},${error_db^^},${source_tbl}^^,${target_tbl^^},${error_tbl^^},${critical_chain_ind},${final_source_count},${final_target_count},0,${hop_validation},${current_timestamp},${current_timestamp}" >> ${control_dir}/live_stats_${file_ext}.txt
    
done < control_entries.txt
```

Contents of `control_entries.txt`

```
p4003_sda_file_movement,HIVE,SDA,FDOP_WRK,FDOP_STG,FDOP_WRK,FDOP_SDA_ETL_BS,FDOP_SDA_ETL_STG,FDOP_SDA_ETL_ERROR
p4004_cash_file_movement,HIVE,CASH,FDOP_WRK,FDOP_STG,FDOP_WRK,FDOP_CASH_ETL_BS,FDOP_CASH_ETL_STG,FDOP_CASH_ETL_ERROR
p4015_mdm_tables,HIVE,MDM,FDOP_WRK,FDOP_FINAL,FDOP_WRK,FDOP_VNDR_PRC_MD_BS,FDOP_VNDR_PRC_MD_HIST,FDOP_MDM_ETL_ERROR
```

Using the above script I am generating a new file with comma separted value for each  line in `control_entries.txt` file.

I am achieving what I want.

Now I would like to make some enhancements.

1. I want to pass a variable like `run_project_name` to the script and read only lines that start with that variable and excecute the above script.

For example

If I pass `run_project_name=p4004_cash_file_movement` as my variable then it should create a file with `p4004_cash_file_movement` details only

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Just use an `if` statement: `if [ "$run_project_name" = "$variable" ]`

Comment: `grep "^${variable}" control_entries.txt`?

Comment: Why are you exporting all the variables?

Comment: Or better: `[ "$run_project_name" = "$variable" ] || continue` inside your loop, and then unlike an `if` you have no need to indent the other contents of the loop.

Comment: ...and as Barmar says, don't export variables unless you _need_ them to be copied into the environment for a specific reason. Environment space is a limited resources -- the more (and larger) variables you put there, the shorter the maximum command-line length you can use.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It's "limited" to megabytes, so I don't think a hundred bytes is significant. Just don't do it because it's unnecessary and code smell. It implies you don't understand what exporting is for.

Comment: This whole thing should probably be an `awk` script.

Comment: And why assignments like `source_db=${source_db}`?

Comment: @Barmar If there's a limit, it can be far less than megabytes. And you don't necessarily know how much of the space was already in use when the script was called.

Comment: @chepner Anything is possible, it's not something I would worry about unless you're exporting thousands of variables.

Comment: @Barmar, ...when did that happen? I remember it being in the range of a few hundred K in the not-so-distant past. That said, it doesn't need to be a few thousand variables; _one_ particularly large variable can near the top-end, if its possible size wasn't considered when code was written.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm having trouble finding the limit, when I search I just find `ARGS_MAX`.

Comment: Linux (I'm pretty sure) has no limit. The limit on macOS is 262KB. I thought I remembered seeing an OS with a 4KB limit once upon a time.

Comment: FYI, I just checked my environment size on a couple of systems, both are around 1500 bytes. So if the limit is a few hundred K, there's plenty of room for a handful of small variables like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `if` statement around the loop body.

```
while IFS=, read -r run_project_name application subject_area source_db target_db error_db source_tbl target_tbl error_tbl
do
    if [ "$run_project_name" = "$variable" ]
    then
        proj_num=$(echo $run_project_name | cut -d_ -f1)
        proj_id="${proj_num:1}"
        P_LOAD_FROM_DATE=$(date -d "$current_batch_date - 1 days" +%Y-%m-%d)
        from_batch_seq_num=5
        P_LOAD_TO_DATE=$(date -d "$current_batch_date - 1 days" +%Y-%m-%d)
        to_batch_seq_num=5
        run_main_session_id=000000
        extract_from_ts=$(echo $P_LOAD_FROM_DATE "00:00:00")
        extract_to_ts=$(echo $P_LOAD_TO_DATE "00:00:00")
        source_db=${source_db}
        target_db=${target_db}
        error_db=${error_db}
        source_tbl=${source_tbl}
        target_tbl=${target_tbl}
        error_tbl${error_tbl}
        current_timestamp=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        critical_chain_ind='Y'
        final_source_count=0
        final_target_count=0
        hop_validation='PASSED'
        file_ext=$(date "+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
        echo "${proj_id},${proj_num},,${run_project_name},${application},${subject_area},${P_LOAD_FROM_DATE},${from_batch_seq_num},${P_LOAD_TO_DATE},${to_batch_seq_num},${run_main_session_id},${extract_from_ts},${extract_to_ts},${source_db^^},${target_db^^},${error_db^^},${source_tbl}^^,${target_tbl^^},${error_tbl^^},${critical_chain_ind},${final_source_count},${final_target_count},0,${hop_validation},${current_timestamp},${current_timestamp}" >> ${control_dir}/live_stats_${file_ext}.txt
    fi
done < control_entries.txt
```

Or to reduce nesting, use `continue` with the opposite condition:

```
while IFS=, read -r run_project_name application subject_area source_db target_db error_db source_tbl target_tbl error_tbl
do
    if [ "$run_project_name" != "$variable" ]
    then continue
    fi

    proj_num=$(echo $run_project_name | cut -d_ -f1)
    proj_id="${proj_num:1}"
    P_LOAD_FROM_DATE=$(date -d "$current_batch_date - 1 days" +%Y-%m-%d)
    from_batch_seq_num=5
    P_LOAD_TO_DATE=$(date -d "$current_batch_date - 1 days" +%Y-%m-%d)
    to_batch_seq_num=5
    run_main_session_id=000000
    extract_from_ts=$(echo $P_LOAD_FROM_DATE "00:00:00")
    extract_to_ts=$(echo $P_LOAD_TO_DATE "00:00:00")
    source_db=${source_db}
    target_db=${target_db}
    error_db=${error_db}
    source_tbl=${source_tbl}
    target_tbl=${target_tbl}
    error_tbl${error_tbl}
    current_timestamp=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    critical_chain_ind='Y'
    final_source_count=0
    final_target_count=0
    hop_validation='PASSED'
    file_ext=$(date "+%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
    echo "${proj_id},${proj_num},,${run_project_name},${application},${subject_area},${P_LOAD_FROM_DATE},${from_batch_seq_num},${P_LOAD_TO_DATE},${to_batch_seq_num},${run_main_session_id},${extract_from_ts},${extract_to_ts},${source_db^^},${target_db^^},${error_db^^},${source_tbl}^^,${target_tbl^^},${error_tbl^^},${critical_chain_ind},${final_source_count},${final_target_count},0,${hop_validation},${current_timestamp},${current_timestamp}" >> ${control_dir}/live_stats_${file_ext}.txt
done < control_entries.txt
```